# How to fix a on mouse hover delete button so that we can delete it by keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see in the picture the tabs welcome, alarm etc. Now if the tab is not selected then only we can delete the tab and the delete button will appear only at the time of mouse hover. Now my question is I want to fix it there so that I can delete it by using keyboard ? (here welcome tab is selected, so we can delete any of the tabs). It is an issue of accessibility.

[image]

css code:

```
.js .delete-tab {
background: url(../images/common/remove.png) no-repeat 42%;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
height: 8px;
position: absolute;
right: 2px;
text-indent: -9999em;
top: 2px;
width: 8px; }
```

javascript:

```
_deleteButton: function(obj) {
        var instance = this;

        obj.append('<span class="delete-tab">X</span>');

        var deleteTab = obj.find('.delete-tab');

        deleteTab.click(
            function(event) {
                instance._removePage(this);
            }
        );

        deleteTab.hide();

        obj.hover(
            function() {
                jQuery(this).find('.delete-tab').fadeIn('fast');
            },
            function() {
                jQuery(this).find('.delete-tab').fadeOut('fast');
            }
        );
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a quick-and-dirty way is to bind the KeyUp event to the document body, and listen for the delete-key (or whatever key you had in mind).
Ie. do the binding on the "hover-in" state of `obj.hover`, and unbinding on the "hover-out" state.

Edit, added example:

```
//Add this method somewhere in you code
function getDeleteBtn(e){
    if(e.which == 46) //46 == delete btn
        alert('delete');
}

obj.hover(
    function(){
        //Add this....
        $('body').bind('keyup', getDeleteBtn);
    },
    function(){
        //And this to your hover statement
        $('body').unbind('keyup', getDeleteBtn); 
    }
);
```

A quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grgKm/

Comment: I'm not expert in jquery, can you please elaborate this a little?

Comment: I've added an example for you